# Why can IE 8 display compressed CSS but other browsers can't display?

Tags: css, browser, compression

I use IIS web server 7.5 on Windows 7 for hosting my project. I try to create Javascript & CSS handler that can optimize and compress both Javascript & Css file size. But I found some problem. Please look at the following request & response of **Test.css** file which I found at Firebug on Firefox 3.0.11 browser.

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control : private
Content-Type : text/html
Content-Encoding : gzip
Server : Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version : 2.0.50727
X-Powered-By : ASP.NET
Date : Tue, 30 Jun 2009 10:46:15 GMT
Content-Length : 197
```

**Request Headers**

```
Host : localhost
User-Agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.11) Gecko/2009060215 Firefox/3.0.11 (.NET CLR
 4.0.20506)
Accept : text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language : en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding : gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset : ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive : 300
Connection : keep-alive
If-Modified-Since : Tue, 30 Jun 2009 10:41:00 GMT
If-None-Match : "1C9F96F41F48600"
Cache-Control : max-age=0
```

Moreover, I opened response tab of test.css file and I found that CSS file is loaded successfully. I try to open the same page in other browser like Chrome 3, Safari 4.0, Opera 10.0. But all browser can't display a correct web page except IE 8. Why?

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#f7f7f7 url(Photoes/bg.jpg) no-repeat center top;}
```

PS. I try to disable compressor and all browser can display correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your response header is incorret:

```
Content-Type : text/html
```

Should be

```
Content-Type : text/css
```

Comment: Still odd it only breaks with compression enabled though. This is probably the cause though.

Comment: Thanks. I forget it. It's default content type.